# How to select the minimum date, EmployeeID and BranchID per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It's been a while since I wrote "complex" queries in SQL...

I have a table `Attendance` with columns

```
BranchID (int)
SignDate (DateTime) 
EmployeeID (nvarchar)
```

Each `Branch` has tens of employees.

What I need is a list the earliest `SignDate` for each branch per day and `EmployeeID` who signed.

I tried several ways, but no luck...

I'm using SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You said you've tried several ways... what have you tried? Is the problem the time component of the `SignDate`? If so then `cast(SignDate as date)`

Comment: What happens if two rows have the same `SignDate` and `BranchId` values but different `EmployeeId` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT BranchID, EmployeeID, SignDate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY BranchID, CONVERT(date, SignDate) 
      ORDER BY SignDate, EmployeeID -- break ties
    )
  FROM dbo.Attendance
  -- some kind of WHERE maybe
)
SELECT BranchID, EmployeeID, SignDate
  FROM src
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY BranchID, SignDate;
```

See also [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/1186).

Comment: Oh dang, I forgot about using `ROW_NUMBER` - I was mentally stuck in MS Access-mode for some reason. Upvoted!